# Android Sound Localization

Tags: android, kotlin, localization, android-mediaplayer, android-sound

Does anyone know how to do **sound/media** Localization in android like we do with strings translations to support different languages in the app? because i didn't find any good resources for this feature.

**EDIT -** This is how i using the media resources files, by the way the strings localization work properly, but the sound not.

I am using SoundPool to play the sound i just pass the resources ID for example R.raw.ecg_recording.

[image]

Comment: You can use the strings localisation to store paths of the sound/media if they are shipped with the app (example: raw/assets) & play relevant media from path depending on the language.

Comment: It depends on how you're using the media files in the first place. For example, if you use resources, the usual variation mechanism works for all resource types.

Comment: After the edit: are you using a wrapped Context to support languages other than the system default? If so, you need to use a similarly wrapped context with SoundPool too.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and quick response, it works!!